# Regex for 4 digits including 0 at first position not working right

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I need a regex which allows only 4 digits and those four can contain 0 at any position.

Below is my code:

View :

```
<label asp-for="UserId"></label><br />
<input asp-for="UserId" class="form-control" maxlength="4" />
<span asp-validation-for="UserId" class="text-danger"></span>
```

Model :

```
[RegularExpression(@"^([0-9]{4})$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter last 4 digits of your user Id.")]
[Display(Name = "Last 4 digits of user Id")]
public int? UserId{ get; set; }
```

But if I type in 0645, it throws an error "Please enter last 4 digits of your user Id.".If I change it to say 4567, it works fine. So how should I fix my regex?

Comment: What error does it throw?

Comment: @Sweeper It gives my error message;Please enter last 4 digits of your user Id.

Comment: Did it throw the same error with `@"^(\d{4})$"` ?

Comment: `0645` gets truncated as an int to `645` change it to string to retain the `0`... The `regex` isn't the issue, the datatype is.

Comment: Remove the redundant parentheses and use `public string UserId{ get; set; }`

Comment: I could not reproduce your issue by using your code.Could you share your version of your project?Did you use `@section Scripts {@{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}}` in your view?

Comment: I believe the problem isn't your regex, but rather your input field.
You have `UserId` defined as an `int`. This will only give you a numeric representation of your input.  Thus `0123` is numerically just `123`.
If you change your input field type to `string` you should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

You do not have any problem with your regex. As was already said in the comments, your property is an integer and when you set its value to 0645 internally it is converted to int and become 645.

If you look into [`RegularExpressionAttibute`](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/DataAnnotations/RegularExpressionAttribute.cs) class, line 59, on GitHub you will realize that the method IsValid receives and object and then parses it as a string.

---

*So lets look at the complete flow of your data.*

1) Your user types a value into a textbox. ("0645")

2) `ModelBinder` converts the string typed into an integer. (645)

3) Inside `RegularExpressionAttibute.IsValid` your integer is converted again into an string ("645")

4) Regular Expression is applied to the value ("645") not ("0645"). So it will not pass your validation.

This is the `RegularExpressionAttibute.IsValid` method.

```
override bool IsValid(object value) {
    this.SetupRegex();

    // Convert the value to a string
    string stringValue = Convert.ToString(value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

    // Automatically pass if value is null or empty. RequiredAttribute should be used to assert a value is not empty.
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(stringValue)) {
        return true;
    }

    Match m = this.Regex.Match(stringValue);

    // We are looking for an exact match, not just a search hit. This matches what
    // the RegularExpressionValidator control does
    return (m.Success && m.Index == 0 && m.Length == stringValue.Length);
}
```

---

*Whats the solution / suggestion?*

You are expecting 4 digits as an input, and until now you don't said anything about have to do any kind of calculation with this.

As you don't need to do any calculation you can keep it as an string without any harm. Just keep validating that your string contains 4 digits (you are already doing it).

And if you need to do any calc in the future just convert the string to integer when its needed.

So just change this line:

`public int? UserId{ get; set; }`

To this:

`public string UserId{ get; set; }`